# How to update this column in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I have a column which has data like:

> 65323231521/Category/SEGKDIWKSNBA/Library/Caches/Animal.jpg

I want to replace any text which precedes /Library/Caches/ with 'Home'. So my update statement should change the column data to

> Home/Library/Caches/Animal.jpg

Here

> 65323231521/Category/SEGKDIWKSNBA

is dynamically generated and is NOT constant.

So, how do I write Update statement in SQLite to get desired result.

Please let me know.

Comment: Do the different `'65323231521/Category/SEGKDIWKSNBA'` substrings have a constant length?

Comment: No. that is also not constant. The approach I think we need is to indentify string preceding /Library/Caches and replace it with 'Home'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to achieve this with the [available functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) in SQLite. You should define a custom function that does this task and use it in your queries.

Comment: i'm glad someone else reached that conclusion!